# Excessive Spaces Between Words

Tags: css, word-spacing

So I am trying to put in titles for a dropdown menu's elements. Whenever the title gets long enough to take up another row(down) the spacing between the words becomes all wonky. I have tried to manipulate the spacing via "word-spacing" in css, but it doesn't seem to work. If anyone could help me on this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: We need code (html, css) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align:left;` instead of `text-align:justify;` (assuming left to right website)